# How to set a constant in rails only once at server initialization so as to not run on rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some rake tasks that run each minute and of course that spawns the environment.rb each time.  I'm needing to set a constant that's dynamically set on server init ONLY at the initial rails server startup, not at every rake task.

How can this be done?  How can I ensure that a particular constant is set only at the primary app startup only once and not on other subsequent rake tasks, etc.?

Comment: rake tasks that run each minute are bad practice, better use daemons/delayed job/something similar instead

Comment: @Mik_Die already using `rufus-scheduler` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just write out your value to a file.  If the file already exists, use the value stored inside it, otherwise create the file and write out the contents using something like `Marshal#load` and `Marshal#dump` if needed?

Just a thought

Comment: Well, looking at that a bit closer and trying it, it doesn't facilitate a setter.

Comment: you can write your own code to set the data in the file.  What kind of object are you trying to store in a constant and retreive?  Just write it out yourself

Comment: Yeah, essentially I'm writing out an ip address.  I think I probably should actually write out the time as well as really all I need to do is to make sure that it doesn't check for the ip more than 1 time per hour.

Comment: sounds simple enough to me to either write it out as a yaml file, or comma separated file or something.